# How can I choose a column of dat file to plot in pgfplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have dat file (output from Matlab) and it has four columns. How can I choose my desire column to plot in pgfplots.

```
 \documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\boldmath
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={line width=1.2pt}}
\pgfplotsset{every tick/.append style={color=black}}
\pgfplotsset{every minor tick/.append style={thin}}
\pgfplotsset{every major tick/.append style={line width=1pt}} %
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot+[very thick,mark=triangle*,mark repeat=1,mark options={scale=1.3}] file{Fre.dat};
\addlegendentry{ $column1-2$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

my dat file is:

```
   0.0000000e+00   9.7322390e+00   1.3985949e+01   1.5525350e+01
   2.5000000e+00   9.7404206e+00   1.4001132e+01   1.5546305e+01
   5.0000000e+00   9.7651029e+00   1.4046619e+01   1.5609681e+01
   7.5000000e+00   9.8067018e+00   1.4122249e+01   1.5717003e+01
   1.0000000e+01   9.8659247e+00   1.4227833e+01   1.5870771e+01
   1.2500000e+01   9.9437917e+00   1.4363269e+01   1.6074399e+01
   1.5000000e+01   1.0041667e+01   1.4528713e+01   1.6332129e+01
   1.7500000e+01   1.0161304e+01   1.4724777e+01   1.6648943e+01
   2.0000000e+01   1.0304897e+01   1.4952727e+01   1.7030511e+01
   2.2500000e+01   1.0475157e+01   1.5214662e+01   1.7483207e+01
   2.5000000e+01   1.0675401e+01   1.5513636e+01   1.8014219e+01
   2.7500000e+01   1.0909671e+01   1.5853762e+01   1.8631749e+01
   3.0000000e+01   1.1182876e+01   1.6240296e+01   1.9345313e+01
   3.2500000e+01   1.1500982e+01   1.6679755e+01   2.0166108e+01
   3.5000000e+01   1.1871246e+01   1.7180085e+01   2.1107451e+01
   3.7500000e+01   1.2302522e+01   1.7750913e+01   2.2185310e+01
   4.0000000e+01   1.2805653e+01   1.8403905e+01   2.3418947e+01
   4.2500000e+01   1.3393986e+01   1.9153253e+01   2.4831704e+01
   4.5000000e+01   1.4084049e+01   2.0016348e+01   2.6045676e+01
   4.7500000e+01   1.4896463e+01   2.1014686e+01   2.7132868e+01
   5.0000000e+01   1.5857171e+01   2.2175104e+01   2.8395420e+01
   5.2500000e+01   1.6999148e+01   2.3531505e+01   2.9867785e+01
   5.5000000e+01   1.8364789e+01   2.5127277e+01   3.1594083e+01
   5.7500000e+01   2.0009352e+01   2.7018776e+01   3.3631631e+01
   6.0000000e+01   2.2006006e+01   2.9280464e+01   3.6056144e+01
```

Comment: Is the answer here to "Plotting .dat file in pgfplot with multiple columns" http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44638/35957 insufficient?

Comment: Did my answer below help you solve your problem? If so, would you please consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1853/30280), so the question is marked as solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the column index for each coordinate using the `x index` or `y index` keys, as in`\addplot file [x index=0, y index=1] {Fre.dat};`. 0 is the index of the first column, as explained in the [`pgfplots` manual](http://ctan.uib.no/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) section 4.3.2.

Example (removed everything not essential to the problem at hand):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{Fre.dat}
   0.0000000e+00   9.7322390e+00   1.3985949e+01   1.5525350e+01
   2.5000000e+00   9.7404206e+00   1.4001132e+01   1.5546305e+01
   5.0000000e+00   9.7651029e+00   1.4046619e+01   1.5609681e+01
   7.5000000e+00   9.8067018e+00   1.4122249e+01   1.5717003e+01
   1.0000000e+01   9.8659247e+00   1.4227833e+01   1.5870771e+01
   1.2500000e+01   9.9437917e+00   1.4363269e+01   1.6074399e+01
   1.5000000e+01   1.0041667e+01   1.4528713e+01   1.6332129e+01
   1.7500000e+01   1.0161304e+01   1.4724777e+01   1.6648943e+01
   2.0000000e+01   1.0304897e+01   1.4952727e+01   1.7030511e+01
   2.2500000e+01   1.0475157e+01   1.5214662e+01   1.7483207e+01
   2.5000000e+01   1.0675401e+01   1.5513636e+01   1.8014219e+01
   2.7500000e+01   1.0909671e+01   1.5853762e+01   1.8631749e+01
   3.0000000e+01   1.1182876e+01   1.6240296e+01   1.9345313e+01
   3.2500000e+01   1.1500982e+01   1.6679755e+01   2.0166108e+01
   3.5000000e+01   1.1871246e+01   1.7180085e+01   2.1107451e+01
   3.7500000e+01   1.2302522e+01   1.7750913e+01   2.2185310e+01
   4.0000000e+01   1.2805653e+01   1.8403905e+01   2.3418947e+01
   4.2500000e+01   1.3393986e+01   1.9153253e+01   2.4831704e+01
   4.5000000e+01   1.4084049e+01   2.0016348e+01   2.6045676e+01
   4.7500000e+01   1.4896463e+01   2.1014686e+01   2.7132868e+01
   5.0000000e+01   1.5857171e+01   2.2175104e+01   2.8395420e+01
   5.2500000e+01   1.6999148e+01   2.3531505e+01   2.9867785e+01
   5.5000000e+01   1.8364789e+01   2.5127277e+01   3.1594083e+01
   5.7500000e+01   2.0009352e+01   2.7018776e+01   3.3631631e+01
   6.0000000e+01   2.2006006e+01   2.9280464e+01   3.6056144e+01 
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot file [x index=0,y index=1] {Fre.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]