# Read data from different files for each frame (animateinline)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, compilation-error, animate

I wish to create a plot of data stored in different files and make an animation of it. But I am getting a `Missing \endcsname inserted` error. Since I'm using "non-text" components in a field where only text is expected, I get the error, which I understand. I am not able to figure out a workaround. Any help is appreciated.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone} 

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}

\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=newest,height=7cm}

\begin{document}

    \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{5}
        \multiframe{10}{iX=2+1}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
                \begin{axis}[scaled ticks=false,xmin=0,ymin=0,ymax=1,legend entries= {$n= \iX$},legend pos=north west, legend style = {font=\scriptsize}]
                    \addplot[color=blue,ultra thick] table {data/n\iX.dat};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \end{animateinline}

    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution presents the approach you wanted with multiple files.

I split each data from each `y` column into a different file and removed some lines.

The main option is `\addplot table {Fre\i.dat};`. A MWE follows.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{animate}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{Fre1.dat}
  0.0000000e+00   9.7322390e+00
  2.5000000e+00   9.7404206e+00
  5.0000000e+00   9.7651029e+00
  7.5000000e+00   9.8067018e+00
  1.0000000e+01   9.8659247e+00
  1.2500000e+01   9.9437917e+00
  1.5000000e+01   1.0041667e+01
  1.7500000e+01   1.0161304e+01
  2.0000000e+01   1.0304897e+01
  2.2500000e+01   1.0475157e+01
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{Fre2.dat}
0.0000000e+00   1.3985949e+01
2.5000000e+00   1.4001132e+01
5.0000000e+00   1.4046619e+01
7.5000000e+00   1.4122249e+01
1.0000000e+01   1.4227833e+01
1.2500000e+01   1.4363269e+01
1.5000000e+01   1.4528713e+01
1.7500000e+01   1.4724777e+01
2.0000000e+01   1.4952727e+01
2.2500000e+01   1.5214662e+01
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{Fre3.dat}
  0.0000000e+00   1.5525350e+01
  2.5000000e+00   1.5546305e+01
  5.0000000e+00   1.5609681e+01
  7.5000000e+00   1.5717003e+01
  1.0000000e+01   1.5870771e+01
  1.2500000e+01   1.6074399e+01
  1.5000000e+01   1.6332129e+01
  1.7500000e+01   1.6648943e+01
  2.0000000e+01   1.7030511e+01
  2.2500000e+01   1.7483207e+01
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[scaled ticks=false,xmin=0,ymin=0, legend entries={$n=1$}, legend pos=north west, legend style = {font=\scriptsize}]
    \addplot table {Fre1.dat};
    \addplot table {Fre2.dat};
    \addplot table {Fre3.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{animateinline}[controls,loop,bb=0 0 250 250]{1}
  \multiframe{3}{i=1+1}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[scaled ticks=false, xmin=0,ymin=0, xmax=30,ymax=20, legend entries={$n=\i$}, legend pos=north west, legend style = {font=\scriptsize}]
        \addplot table {Fre\i.dat};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

The animation is presented alongside the base graph.

[image]

Comment: @Dhruv Thakkar, does this fit your needs? I don't know exactly how this will behave along files with multiple columns, but that's a good start point.

Comment: yes it does. Can you please tell me how it's different from my approach? I mean apart from the inline definition of the file. Isn't it the same?

Comment: I *think* you had an issue with `standalone`, I saw [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/492981/140133) and then I changed it to article. I also changed `\iX` to `\i` but that's was not the cause.

Comment: I copied your code and replaced "Fre" with "n" to access my files, while keeping all of it the same, I still get the error. Also, I noted something interesting that if I remove ```animateinline``` environment and add ```\def\iX{9}``` I don't get the error.

Comment: *More precisely*. The code I gave works with `standalone`. It seems to be some issue with `ymax=1`.

Answer (score 1):

This solution presents a slight different approach to your issue. It animates dates from a single file with multiple columns.

I used:

- [Plotting .dat file in pgfplot with multiple columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44637/140133)
- [How can I choose a column of dat file to plot in pgfplot?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/291442/140133)

The main option is `y index=\i`. A MWE follows.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{animate}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{Fre.dat}
  0.0000000e+00   9.7322390e+00   1.3985949e+01   1.5525350e+01
  2.5000000e+00   9.7404206e+00   1.4001132e+01   1.5546305e+01
  5.0000000e+00   9.7651029e+00   1.4046619e+01   1.5609681e+01
  7.5000000e+00   9.8067018e+00   1.4122249e+01   1.5717003e+01
  1.0000000e+01   9.8659247e+00   1.4227833e+01   1.5870771e+01
  1.2500000e+01   9.9437917e+00   1.4363269e+01   1.6074399e+01
  1.5000000e+01   1.0041667e+01   1.4528713e+01   1.6332129e+01
  1.7500000e+01   1.0161304e+01   1.4724777e+01   1.6648943e+01
  2.0000000e+01   1.0304897e+01   1.4952727e+01   1.7030511e+01
  2.2500000e+01   1.0475157e+01   1.5214662e+01   1.7483207e+01
  2.5000000e+01   1.0675401e+01   1.5513636e+01   1.8014219e+01
  2.7500000e+01   1.0909671e+01   1.5853762e+01   1.8631749e+01
  3.0000000e+01   1.1182876e+01   1.6240296e+01   1.9345313e+01
  3.2500000e+01   1.1500982e+01   1.6679755e+01   2.0166108e+01
  3.5000000e+01   1.1871246e+01   1.7180085e+01   2.1107451e+01
  3.7500000e+01   1.2302522e+01   1.7750913e+01   2.2185310e+01
  4.0000000e+01   1.2805653e+01   1.8403905e+01   2.3418947e+01
  4.2500000e+01   1.3393986e+01   1.9153253e+01   2.4831704e+01
  4.5000000e+01   1.4084049e+01   2.0016348e+01   2.6045676e+01
  4.7500000e+01   1.4896463e+01   2.1014686e+01   2.7132868e+01
  5.0000000e+01   1.5857171e+01   2.2175104e+01   2.8395420e+01
  5.2500000e+01   1.6999148e+01   2.3531505e+01   2.9867785e+01
  5.5000000e+01   1.8364789e+01   2.5127277e+01   3.1594083e+01
  5.7500000e+01   2.0009352e+01   2.7018776e+01   3.3631631e+01
  6.0000000e+01   2.2006006e+01   2.9280464e+01   3.6056144e+01 
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[scaled ticks=false,xmin=0,ymin=0, legend entries={$n=1$}, legend pos=north west, legend style = {font=\scriptsize}]
    \addplot table [x index=0,y index=1] {Fre.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{animateinline}[controls,loop,bb=0 0 250 250]{1}
  \multiframe{3}{i=1+1}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[scaled ticks=false, xmin=0,ymin=0, xmax=70,ymax=40, legend entries={$n=\i$}, legend pos=north west, legend style = {font=\scriptsize}]
        \addplot table [x index=0,y index=\i] {Fre.dat};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

The animation is presented alongside the base graph.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But the problem is that I have files with a different number of rows and multiple columns(one for x, changes in each file, and one for y). Any thoughts on how I can circumvent it?

Comment: Indeed, when you were writing I was editing another answer with data from a file.